# Ruby on Rails website: Adding/Removing Active Class to Navbar

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, navbar

I'm building a static website in Ruby on Rails and I have an **application.html.erb** file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>BayEquities</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render "layouts/shim" %>
 </head>
 <body>
  <%= render "layouts/header" %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $('.navbar .nav > li > a').click(function(e){
       $('.navbar .nav > li.active').removeClass('active')
       $(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
    });
  });
</script>
```

Currently this code adds the active class and removes it accordingly. The only issue is that the header partial (code below) reloads every time a new navbar link is clicked. Thus applying the active class to "Home" after every click.

**_header.html.erb**

```
<header class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
   <a class="brand" id="logo">Bay Equities</a>
   <ul class="nav">
    <li class="active"><%= link_to "Home", "index" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Services", "services" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", "contact" %></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

I apologize in advance for the rushed formatting job, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548911/ruby-on-rails-highlight-current-link-on-navigation-bar

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you considered moving this logic to rails?

For example you could setup a helper method that assigns the active class based on params[:action].

```
module ApplicationHelper  

  def is_active(action)       
    params[:action] == action ? "active" : nil        
  end

end
```

And then in your partial for your home link:

```
<li class="<%=is_active('home')%>"><%= link_to "Home", "index" %></li>
<li class="<%=is_active('services')%>"><%= link_to "Services", "services" %></li>
<li class="<%=is_active('contact')%>"><%= link_to "Contact Us", "contact" %></li>
```

Comment: And why was I ever thinking about doing this in javascript?  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Add below class in `application_helper.rb`

```
def current_class_by(path:)
    return 'active' if request.path == path ''
end
```

Menu link looks something similar to like this.

```
<%= link_to(dashboard_path, class: "nav-link #{current_class_by(path: dashboard_path)}") do %>
    <i class="nav-icon __icon-tachometer"></i>
    <p><%= t('dashboard_admin.menus.dashboard') %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This answer adds nothing more than the original answer of 8 years ago.